# How to use pure CSS to control other elements under same parent?

Tags: html, css, hover, selector, parent

here is the simple example from codepen [Codepen](http://codepen.io/FlyC/pen/MyVroR)

I'm trying to make a few area which belong to the same parent element,
and when I hover one of them, the others' opacity will decrease, or something else style changing.

For example, when I hover the second element, the first element which has the same parent would change its `background-color`.

I use the word **area** at the first paragraph means the child doesn't really have to be a `div`, it could be a `li` or a `p` or other elements.
to solve this problem, it could be any type of element.

html looks like this:

```
<!-- html -->
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

I tried `E ~ F` rule to solve this problem, and I've already known it will only work at the first `div` which is the first child of parent.

except javascript, is there any other way to make this feature with pure css?
thx

Comment: u want to change css of all other elements except the hovered once..or the previous only?

Comment: You can use the siblings selector "+" , for reference:  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/adjacent-sibling/

Comment: You can select the previous element using CSS. You'll have to use Javascript for that. Other option which you can consider is positioning them and then using hover rule

Comment: Something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGRpdZ

Comment: @GauravAggarwal sorry I didn't make my question more clearly, I want to change css of all other elements except the hover one

Comment: Ya but if you want to select previous elements with css there is not css for this as i referred in my answer...you can use Aziz css trick for this.

Comment: I see, hope css can select previous elements soon in future. I gonna use Aziz's answer for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover the `.parent`, change the style of all children that are not hovered as well ([pen](http://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/NNYXOE)):

```
.parent {
  width: 100px; /** limit the width of the parent, so you can't hover it, without hovering one of the children as well **/
  margin:10px;

  &:hover > div:not(:hover) { /** only change the background of divs you don't hover as well **/
    background: red;
  }

  div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
  }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could use `display: inline-block` to the parent, instead of giving it a defined width (width becomes based on children)

Comment: Indeed. That was my initial idea. However, I wasn't clear about your general layout. You can also use position: absolute, for the same reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You create that by applying double hover states:

```css
.parent:hover div {
  opacity:0.5;
}

.parent:hover div:hover {
  opacity:1;
}

.parent div {
  border:1px dashed #CCC;
  padding:1em;
  margin:1em;
  background:#666;
  color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
    <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's close, if the opacity won't decrease while the mouse haven't touch the child element it will be great.   but the 'double hover 'states really gives me some idea to solve this problem , thx!

Comment: the opacity does not change unless you hover over the parent... how else did you want this?

Comment: opacity won't change unless I hover the child. once I hover the child, the other child's opacity will change. something like this... thx

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, `~` is for general successor sibling (meaning the element comes after this one, but not necessarily immediately after) and is a CSS3 selector. `+` is for next sibling and is CSS2.1.

See [Adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) from [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and [5.7 Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) from [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cover.html#minitoc).